# Prevent Object Release in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I'm looking after a solution to prevent object release in storyboard views.
Here is the deal, I have a storyboard view which contains data grabbed from JSON. This view has relation with another view (First View:List of items -- Second View:Item Details). Now when I tap on an item in first view, it goes to another view and shows the detail (using segue). BUT when I go back to the first view, it needs to grab the data from JSON again. (makes the user angry)

I'm aware of using Tab template, but I can't due to the application user requirements.

I'll be so much appreciated if anybody could help me.

Gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do a modal Segue from your First View to the Second View.  Then when you are finished with the Second View execute [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in the Second View to dismiss the Second View and return to the First View.  This should then display the First View once more with the data.

Comment: I do use modal segue. what if I have more than two relational view like this View1 --> View2 -->> View3. Does it work for this?

on view3 dismiss would bring up view2 and view1 accordingly?!

Comment: Yes if you have a Modal Segue from View 1 to View 2 and then from view 2 to View 3.  Then for example a dismiss button on View 2 and then again on View 3 and you execute [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  in the IBAction method for each of these dismiss buttons it should work.  View 3 should return to View 2 and View 2 to View 1.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That Worked pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly implementing the [Model-View-Controller pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html). Views should never fetch or hold data. They simply display it. View Controllers also do not hold data. Views and view controllers can be thrown away any time they're not on screen. This is by design.

Create a model class that is responsible for talking to the server and holding the resulting data. The controller should hand the model to the view, and the view should just display what it finds in the model.